# Fragment Switching in the same Activity restarts the same Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on an application.
Somewhere I want to load a Fragment in an Activity and when a Gridview/Listview item will be clicked on the **FirstFragment**, I load the **SecondFragment**

I have added the Fragments the way below:

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.form_creation_view);

    Fragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.form_view, fragment).commit();

}
```

Second Fragment:

```
Fragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.form_view, fragment).commit();
```

**OnBackPress of MainActivity.java** :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

So, when I press the BackButton on the Mainactivity when SecondFragment is loaded, it switches to the FirstFragment, but it calls the `onCreateView()` method of the FirstFragment again.

The FirstFragment has a Recyclerview inside and I send an API request in the `OnCreateView()` method to the server in order to load the data into this Recyclerview.

Now when I come back again to this Fragment from the SecondFragment, I want the it so that the request should not be executed and the data should be populated into the RecyclerView.

How can I achieve this?
Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: Start by using `fragmentTransaction.replace` instead of `fragmentTransaction.add` in the onCreate method of your Activity. Then, I'd change the way you manage the Fragment state in the `onBackPressed()` method

Comment: one thing you could do is save the time of the request and before starting it check when was last time you did it

Comment: One simple way is set a flag, while 2ndFragment end, change flag value, so that you can check flag value when 1stFragment's onCreateView() been execute.

Answer (score 1):

in your onCreateView, you should do a check like this:

```
    if(mList.size() == 0){
        //make api call
    }else{
        //set recyclerView adapter
    }
```

This way, when you come back from the SecondFragment you can repopulate the RecyclerView.

You should also consider saving this list on onSaveInstanceState